# Why setting $window.location.href does not work when set inside a promise?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I send request to the server and want conditionally redirect to another page (not angular) after response is received. Thus navigation happens inside `then` part of a promise.

I tried:

```
$location.path(url)
```

and

```
$window.location.href = url;
$windo.location.reload();
```

nothing works.

But if I wrap either of these two calls with `setTimeout(navigate,0)` redirection occurs.
Seems like Angular guards url during digest cycle.

Can anyone clarify or share the links explaining what really happens.

Comment: Probably some angular digest related thing. This should work fine I think: `window.location.href = url;`.

Comment: @dfsq Yes, this works =) But it's like "Use the force, Luke" =)

Comment: I found a comment in the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#replace-method) docs that mentions how changes to `$location` are queued within a digest cycle. In addition, I can see how the [$location service source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/1efaf3dc136f822703a9cda55afac7895a923ccb/src/ng/location.js) is waiting to sync the URL with the browser until certain angular events occur. However, I haven't quite grokked how this all fits together. I hope these resources aid others...

Comment: @Benjm setTimeout worked only with $window.locatin.href   @location.path() redirected to the angulars root page (/)

Comment: Hm. Are you using `$http` or `$resource` to make your server communication?

Comment: @Benmj Yes. $http.post(...).then(...trying to redirect here...)

Comment: Do you know the value of `url`? `$location.path` expects a path string (after the hashbang, or whatever your HTML5 base is), and will return the root '/' if it gets something else. [Source for $location.path](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/1efaf3dc136f822703a9cda55afac7895a923ccb/src/ng/location.js#L416)

Comment: @Benmj As far as I understand $location is for navigation within angular app. I have full url of another mvc controller and action.

Answer (score 1):

After doing the change, and before ending the promise handler, try doing:

```
$scope.$$phase || $scope.$apply();
```

That should populate the changes.

Comment: well, it's executed inside a digest cycle.  After several restarts and CTrl+F5 it just got working with simple update of $window.location.href. Do not understand why.