# $location.path() from within a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to change the location after a promise is returned, however, the location will not change.

```
function register() {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.email, $scope.password)
    .then(function (user) {
        console.log(user);
        UserService.setUser(user);
        $location.path('/home');
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        $scope.message = error.message;
        alert($scope.message);
    });
}
```

I'm assuming this is because it's within a promise's `.then` function, but I don't see documentation on $location that says it can't be used within a promise.

The console shows the user that was created and there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

From the [AngularJS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

## When should I use $location?

Any time your application needs to react to a change in the current URL or if you want to change the current URL in the browser.

## What does it not do?

It does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed. **To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API, $window.location.href**.

Comment: I don't think window.location.href will work either, as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406338/why-setting-window-location-href-does-not-work-when-set-inside-a-promise

Comment: You're right and there's some talk about a digest cycle issue.  Maybe the problem will correct itself after a restart or two.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related with the angular digest cycles.
To solve it, you can do:

```
$location.path('/home');
$rootScope.$apply();
```

Comment: Also don't forget to inject $rootScope in the declaration of your module.